# how to get text from edittext inside a dialog

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Like the title said how can I get text out of EditText which is found inside a custom dialog?

This is the onCreateDialog method from my dialogfragment:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_dialog, null))
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.name_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   EditText nameEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
                   editor.putString(getString(R.string.name_key), nameEditText.getText().toString());
                   editor.commit();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.name_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   NameDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

I can't get it to work.. I write something in the edittext then i press OK and it just crashes and gives me a null pointer error on this line :

```
editor.putString(getString(R.string.name_key), nameEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `(EditText) getActivity()` -> `(EditText) dialog`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the EditText at the wrong View. Its not part of the Activity, its part of the dialog. So check the dialog for the view:

```
 Dialog dialogView = dialog.getDialog();
 EditText paymentEt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_payment);
```

Comment: thanks :) I thought I might need to use something else instead of getActivity() but I tried giving it the fragmentmanager

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`EditText nameEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);`

try using this

```
Dialog dialg = (Dialog) dialog;
EditText et = (EditText) dialg.findViewById(R.id.search_input_text);
val = et.getText().toString();
```