# How to access EditText data in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

My question is how to get data that users input into my `EditText` then show the data by using `Toast.makeTest` method.

I don't know how to access to the `EditText` in my fragment
and this link didn't worked for me:
[getText from a EditText in a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037381/gettext-from-a-edittext-in-a-dialogfragment)

This is my code:

```
public class FragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {
EditText entry;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)

 {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(R.layout.alert_dialog).setTitle("Add your text").setMessage("HElllloooooooo").setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), entry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),  entry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Comment: I did't see anything related to edittext.

Comment: thats it , couldnt implement it

Comment: What you mean not implemented? You need to include edittext in dialog or you need access edittext from dialog or fragment..

Comment: can you use explain it ?how to do ?

Comment: Since your question is not clear you want editext input from `dialog` or  `fragment` or `activity`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getText from a EditText in a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037381/gettext-from-a-edittext-in-a-dialogfragment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018709/how-to-get-text-from-edittext-inside-a-dialog

Comment: check out my answer , it will help for sure @Yuri

Comment: thanks @MohamedMohaideenAH for your introducing the page  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037381/gettext-from-a-edittext-in-a-dialogfragment it didnt solved my problem

Comment: @Yuri Update your dialog code for showing dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How Edit Text Works:**

First you should bind it:

```
entry =  view.findViewById(R.id.MyEdtText);
```

Second To access the written data(text) in the edit you should call:

```
entry.getText().toString()
```

To Show the written text in Toast you have to:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(entry.getText().toString()){
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Text Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The Text Entered Is"+  entry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**The specific solution for your case is:**

```
    public class FragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {
   private EditText entry;



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View DialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog,null);

        entry = DialogView.findViewById(R.id.entryEditText); // replace it with the correct XML ID

        builder.setView(DialogView).setTitle("Add your text").setMessage("HElllloooooooo").setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "canceled operation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "the edit text value: "+entry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And to show the dialog , call in your activity the following code:

```
FragmentDialog dialog = new FragmentDialog();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "YourDialog");
```

**Proof of concept(See how it works):**

[image: blob:https://imgur.com/1c2f5429-d11f-4f5e-b276-7b7fb84abaf8]

Comment: i did it ,but the toast is empty

Comment: @Yuri check the answer now I have added more code to it , and I have tried it and it successfully worked! :) please upvote and accept as answer if it works with you

Comment: @Yuri I added a GIF showing you how it fully works :D

Comment: thanks getFragmentManager() in mainActivity worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to findViewbyId on onCreateView like below

```
  public class FragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {
    EditText entry;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_username, container);
          entry = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
          mEditText.requestFocus();

          return view;
        }}
```

Comment: thanks , you mean change     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)  To         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)